# PG log : could not (re)acquire exclusive lock for truncate scan

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

PG logs are getting fill with

**2019-03-08 07:01:20 PST LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "hpdpidb.hpdpidb_app.dp_catalog_object_versession": could not (re)acquire exclusive lock for truncate scan**

Can anyone tell about this logging message? Why I am getting this? Do I need to worry about this? How to ignore/fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message mostly means that you should upgrade PostgreSQL to a later version.

It was removed from the code in [this commit](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=5fc893760f60d57aca30163796db1abe516b3fac) in April 2013.

The message itself is nothing to worry about: it means that `VACUUM` could not truncate (reduce in size) a table whose last pages have become empty.

In current PostgreSQL versions, the corresponding message has been reduced to log level `DEBUG2`, so it wouldn't show up in your log.

Comment: Ok, I will upgrade to latest version but for time being can I stop somehow logging to PostgreSQL logs? It's consuming my disk space.

Comment: This is unrelated… Just edit `postgresql.conf` appropriately. Maybe there is something interesting in the log...